# Does MySQL have a way to limit update/insert statement times?

Tags: mysql

This is similar to the statement_timeout of postgresql.

I'm looking to have the query error if it takes longer than x seconds.

I'm aware of SET MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, but that only affects select queries, not update/insert queries.

Comment: MariaDB has one or two timeouts like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the time you are trying to limit is spent waiting for locks, you could use `lock_wait_timeout` (for metadata locks, default is 1 year) or `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` (for row locks, default is 50 seconds).

If the time is spent after locks have been acquired, that is the execution time is taking too long, then no, I don't think MySQL has any query timeout for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Comment: I think the 50 is much too long.  In my opinion, if you have a transaction lasting longer than 5 seconds, you have a structural problem.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. Nevertheless, the default innodb lock wait timeout value in current versions of MySQL is 50 seconds.